# How can I write a fully declarative configuration in Optaplanner if some with<X> methods are missing (there are set<X> methods)

Tags: optaplanner

I use Optaplanner as an optimisation library. I am trying to move away from XML configuration but I noticed that some of the `*MoveSelectorConfig` and `*EntitySelectorConfig` classes have `set<X>` methods instead of `with<X>` methods (e.g. `setEntityClass()`, `setId()`, `setCacheType()`, `setSelectionOrder()`). This makes it not possible to write a fully declarative configuration. Is this intended? What is the rationale? Are there plans to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most definitely not intended, rather an oversight. If you want to report which builder methods are missing, we will eventually fix that. That said, since the setters are always there, this is not critical.

Comment: Done: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2883